# Function to give 2 free product options in CartThrob

Tags: cartthrob

I'm using CartThrob to sell tickets. I create a channel entry for each day and then use options for Adult, Child and Student tickets. I'm trying to write a function for an extension that would give the purchaser 2 free Child tickets whenever they purchase an Adult ticket.

The function I tried to write is as follows;

```
function cartthrob_reduce_tour_inventory()
{
    foreach ($this->EE->cartthrob->cart->items() as $item)
    {
        if($item->item_options('ticket_type') == "Adult")
        {
            //add two child tickets to cart
            $item->item_options('ticket_type') == "Child")->set_quantity() * 2);
            //set the price to free
            $item->set_price(0);
        }
    }

    return; 
}
```

This is the first time I have tried to write a function here, so please excuse what is probably nowhere near what it needs to be. I would be grateful if someone might be able to help? :)

Thank you.

Here's the code in full for the extension:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cartthrob_tour_group_pricing_ext
{
    public $settings = array();
    public $name = 'CartThrob Tour Group Pricing';
    public $version = '1.0.1';
    public $description = 'Reduces child inventory by 2 when an adult ticket is selected. Handles flat rate for 10 or more tickets.';
    public $settings_exist = 'y';
    public $docs_url = 'http://barrettnewton.com';

    protected $EE;

    public function __construct($settings = '')
    {
    $this->EE =& get_instance();
    $this->settings = $settings;
    }


    public function activate_extension()
    {

        $this->EE->db->insert(
            'extensions',
            array(
            'class' => __CLASS__,
            'method' => 'cartthrob_reduce_inventory',
            'hook'  => 'cartthrob_on_authorize',
            'settings' => serialize($this->settings),
            'priority' => 10,
            'version' => $this->version,
            'enabled' => 'y'
            )
        );          
        $this->EE->db->insert(
            'extensions',
            array(
            'class' => __CLASS__,
            'method' => 'cartthrob_set_group_prices',
            'hook'  => 'cartthrob_add_to_cart_end',
            'settings' => serialize($this->settings),
            'priority' => 10,
            'version' => $this->version,
            'enabled' => 'y'
            )
        );
        $this->EE->db->insert(
            'extensions',
            array(
            'class' => __CLASS__,
            'method' => 'cartthrob_set_group_prices',
            'hook'  => 'cartthrob_multi_add_to_cart_end',
            'settings' => serialize($this->settings),
            'priority' => 10,
            'version' => $this->version,
            'enabled' => 'y'
            )
        );
        $this->EE->db->insert(
            'extensions',
            array(
            'class' => __CLASS__,
            'method' => 'cartthrob_set_group_prices',
            'hook'  => 'cartthrob_update_cart_end',
            'settings' => serialize($this->settings),
            'priority' => 10,
            'version' => $this->version,
            'enabled' => 'y'
            )
        );
    }
    public function update_extension($current='')
    {
        if ($current == '' OR $current == $this->version)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $this->EE->db->update(
            'extensions',
            array('version' => $this->version),
            array('class' => __CLASS__)
        );
    }
    public function disable_extension()
    {
    $this->EE->db->delete('extensions', array('class' => __CLASS__));
    }


    function settings()
    {
        $settings = array();

        $settings['quota']                  = array('i', '', "10");
        $settings['adult_group_rate']       = array('i', '', "9.00");
        $settings['child_group_rate']       = array('i', '', "3.60");
        $settings['student_group_rate']     = array('i', '', "7.20");

        return $settings;
    }

    function cartthrob_reduce_tour_inventory()
    {
        foreach ($this->EE->cartthrob->cart->items() as $item)
        {
            if($item->item_options('tour_pass_type') == "Adult")
            {
                //add two child tickets to cart
                $item->item_options('tour_pass_type') == "Child")->set_quantity() * 2);
                //set the price to free
                $item->item_options('tour_pass_type') == "Child")->set_price(0);
            }
        }

        return; 
    }
    function cartthrob_set_tour_group_prices()
    {
        $ticket_count = array();
        foreach($this->EE->cartthrob->cart->items() as $item)
        {
            if($item->item_options('tour_pass_time'))
            {
                $ticket_date = $item->title();
                $ticket_time = $item->item_options('tour_pass_time');
                if(!isset($ticket_count[$ticket_date.$ticket_time]))
                {
                    $ticket_count[$ticket_date.$ticket_time]['count'] = 0;
                    $ticket_count[$ticket_date.$ticket_time]['items'] = array();
                }
                // need to keep the original price stored somewhere in case we need to revert back to the non-group rate
                if(!$item->meta('original_price'))
                {
                    $item->set_meta('original_price', $item->price());
                }
                $ticket_count[$ticket_date.$ticket_time]['count'] += $item->quantity();
                $ticket_count[$ticket_date.$ticket_time]['items'][] = $item;
            }
        }
        // check the number of tickets being purchased
        foreach($ticket_count as $ticket)
        {
            // is the number of tickets being purchased equal to or greater than the quota?
            if($ticket['count'] >= $this->settings['quota'])
            {
                // evaluate each ticket item
                foreach($ticket['items'] as $ticket_item)
                {
                    //if statement here to set price per ticket type


                    // set the price of each item to appropriate rate
                    $ticket_item->set_price($this->settings[$ticket_item->meta('ticket_peak_rate')]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach($ticket['items'] as $ticket_item)
                {
                    // set the price of each item to the original price
                    $ticket_item->set_price($ticket_item->meta('original_price'));
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    // END
}
//END CLASS
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what's not working with your function? We can't help if we don't know what the problem is :)

Comment: Hey Adrian. It's not working at all. :) This is my first attempt at writing a function to do the task I wish to accomplish, so i'm really looking for someone to tell me if i'm on the right path with it.

Comment: Can you post a link to your full extension code? Are you sure the extension is registered correctly? (e.g. does your code run at all?)

Comment: Hey Adrian. I've added the full code above. The extension won't install properly and I think it's to do with the cartthrob_reduce_tour_inventory function. The extensions page just goes blank. :/

Comment: If you're getting a white screen, it's usually a PHP error which isn't being displayed. Try setting `$debug = 1;` in your main EE `index.php` and `admin.php` files.

Comment: Have you considered writing a CartThrob discount plugin rather than an EE extension? Not sure if I missed something here but I would investigate the CartThrob plugin route if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Hey Anthony. Yeah, sorry - this is an Cartthrob extension i'm writing :)